# mysqli auto increment jumping numbers

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm having some issues where the id that is returned from mysql is incorrect. My code creates  a collection, I then take the id returned from the database and pass it to another function that adds items to the database passing the id for the collection as a parameter to make a relation.

```
  // Create new collection
  private function createCollection( $item )
  {    
    $query = "INSERT INTO collection VALUES (
        '',
        ' " . $item['title_en'] ."',
        ' " . $item['title_cy'] ."',
        ' " . $item['description_en'] ."',
        ' " . $item['description_cy'] ."',
        ' " . $tagString . " ',
        ' " . $item['cover'] . " ',
        ' " . $item['guid'] . " ',
        ' " . $item['website'] . " ',
        ' " . $item['date'] . " ',
        '',
        ''
    )";

    $this->mysqli->query($query);    

    $collectionId = $this->mysqli->insert_id;

    echo "\nAdded item with id $collectionId\n";

    $this->addItemToDatabase( $item , $collectionId );
  }

  // Create item
  private function addItemToDatabase( $item , $collectionId )
  {
    foreach($item['items'] as $i) {
      $query = "INSERT INTO items VALUES (
          '',
          ' " . $i['title'] ."',
          ' " . $i['description'] ."',
          ' " . $i['creator'] . " ',
          ' " . $i['owner'] . " ',
          ' " . $i['image'] . " ',
          ' " . $i['date'] . " ',
          ' " . $collectionId . " ',
          '',
          ''
      )";

      $this->mysqli->query($query);     
    }
  }
```

The issue is after a while the ids that come back from the database are incorrect

```
Added item with id 47
Added item with id 48
Added item with id 49
Added item with id 50
Added item with id 51
Added item with id 664
Added item with id 52
Added item with id 670
Added item with id 676
Added item with id 53
Added item with id 54
Added item with id 55
Added item with id 736
Added item with id 56
Added item with id 57
Added item with id 767
Added item with id 58
Added item with id 59
Added item with id 796
Added item with id 60
Added item with id 61
Added item with id 834
Added item with id 62
Added item with id 846
```

There are no collections with an id in the hundreds in the database. I'm not too sure why mysqli is returning incorrect numbers that don't exist.

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.40, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Think I've solved my own issue, one of the titles I was inserting had a single quote `'` which was escaping the insert causing the issue, not sure why it would return a id as a response though